# islice and cycle with multiple levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

**UPDATE**:
Added the pattern required as asked
I have 2 lists and the expected output is different than the last time

```
Numberset1 = [10,11,12]
Numberset2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and i want to display output by manipulating the lists, the expected output is

```
10 1 1
10 1 2
10 1 3
10 1 4
10 1 5
10 2 2
10 2 3
10 2 4
10 2 5
10 2 1
10 3 3
10 3 4
10 3 5
10 3 1
10 3 2
10 4 4
10 4 5
10 4 1
10 4 2
10 4 3
10 5 5
10 5 1
10 5 2
10 5 3
10 5 4
11 2 2
11 2 3
11 2 4
11 2 5
11 2 1
11 3 3
11 3 4
11 3 5
11 3 1
11 3 2
11 4 4
11 4 5
11 4 1
11 4 2
11 4 3
11 5 5
11 5 1
11 5 2
11 5 3
11 5 4
11 5 1
11 1 1
11 1 2
11 1 3
11 1 4
11 1 5
12 3 3
12 3 4
12 3 5
12 3 1
12 3 2
12 4 4
12 4 5
12 4 1
12 4 2
12 4 3
12 4 4
12 4 5
12 5 5
12 5 1
12 5 2
12 5 3
12 1 1
12 1 2
12 1 3
12 1 4
12 1 5
12 2 2
12 2 3
12 2 4
12 2 5
12 2 1
```

The code i have tried is as follows, this was suggested in previous question and i tried using it for the next level of looping but i could not get the desired output

```
Numberset1 = [10,11,12]
Numberset2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

from itertools import cycle, islice

it = cycle(Numberset2)
for i in Numberset1:
    for a in Numberset2:
        for j in islice(it, len(Numberset2)):
            print(i, a,j)
        skipped1 = next(it)
    skipped1 = next(it)
```

The output i am getting is

```
10 1 1
10 1 2
10 1 3
10 1 4
10 1 5
10 2 2
10 2 3
10 2 4
10 2 5
10 2 1
10 3 3
10 3 4
10 3 5
10 3 1
10 3 2
10 4 4
10 4 5
10 4 1
10 4 2
10 4 3
10 5 5
10 5 1
10 5 2
10 5 3
10 5 4
11 1 2
11 1 3
11 1 4
11 1 5
11 1 1
11 2 3
11 2 4
11 2 5
11 2 1
11 2 2
11 3 4
11 3 5
11 3 1
11 3 2
11 3 3
11 4 5
11 4 1
11 4 2
11 4 3
11 4 4
11 5 1
11 5 2
11 5 3
11 5 4
11 5 5
12 1 3
12 1 4
12 1 5
12 1 1
12 1 2
12 2 4
12 2 5
12 2 1
12 2 2
12 2 3
12 3 5
12 3 1
12 3 2
12 3 3
12 3 4
12 4 1
12 4 2
12 4 3
12 4 4
12 4 5
12 5 2
12 5 3
12 5 4
12 5 5
12 5 1
```

Please note the change when the number 11 starts in the first column than the expected output

How can we use cycle and islice for multiple levels

**Pattern**:
    The first column should be in order of numbers in Numberset1, the second column for first number in Numberset1 should be in order of numbers in Numberset2, the 3rd column for first number in Numberset1 should be in order of numbers in NUmberset2 but when the 2nd column for first number in Numberset1 changes it should also change and print from 2ndnumber in Numberset2 list and so on

Comment: Can you describe what the pattern is supposed to be? It seems to break down a bit once the first column hits 12.

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version that accomplishes the task using `cycle` and `islice`. To make the code cleaner I've created a generator function `aligned_cycle` which cycles through the items yielded by `cycle` until we get the one we want to start the current cycle with.

This updated version can cope with `Numberset1` having greater length than `Numberset2`.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def aligned_cycle(seq, start_item):
    ''' Make a generator that cycles over the items in `seq`.
        The first item yielded equals `start_item`.
    '''
    if start_item not in seq:
        raise ValueError("{} not in {}".format(start_item, seq))
    it = cycle(seq)
    for u in it:
        if u == start_item:
            break
    yield u
    yield from it

Numberset1 = [10, 11, 12]
Numberset2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cycle_length = len(Numberset2)

for i, u in zip(Numberset1, cycle(Numberset2)):
    for j in islice(aligned_cycle(Numberset2, u), cycle_length):
        for k in islice(aligned_cycle(Numberset2, j), cycle_length):
            print(i, j, k)
```

**output**

```
10 1 1
10 1 2
10 1 3
10 1 4
10 1 5
10 2 2
10 2 3
10 2 4
10 2 5
10 2 1
10 3 3
10 3 4
10 3 5
10 3 1
10 3 2
10 4 4
10 4 5
10 4 1
10 4 2
10 4 3
10 5 5
10 5 1
10 5 2
10 5 3
10 5 4
11 2 2
11 2 3
11 2 4
11 2 5
11 2 1
11 3 3
11 3 4
11 3 5
11 3 1
11 3 2
11 4 4
11 4 5
11 4 1
11 4 2
11 4 3
11 5 5
11 5 1
11 5 2
11 5 3
11 5 4
11 1 1
11 1 2
11 1 3
11 1 4
11 1 5
12 3 3
12 3 4
12 3 5
12 3 1
12 3 2
12 4 4
12 4 5
12 4 1
12 4 2
12 4 3
12 5 5
12 5 1
12 5 2
12 5 3
12 5 4
12 1 1
12 1 2
12 1 3
12 1 4
12 1 5
12 2 2
12 2 3
12 2 4
12 2 5
12 2 1
```

---

[Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) has written a more robust and more efficient version of `aligned_cycle`:

```
def aligned_cycle(iterable, start_item):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    b = cycle(b)
    for u, v in zip(a, b):
        if u == start_item:
            break
    else:
        return

    yield u
    yield from b
```

Thanks, Jon!

Comment: how can we use islice and cycle to get the desired output is my question. Thanks for posting this anyways

Comment: This works ,however if i add more numbers in Numberset1 it does not work

Comment: number of items in list should be fixed one? regardless of number of items in the lists cant we get the output?

Comment: @Python_newbie Sorry, I don't understand. Can you try explaining that again? And you didn't answer my question.  If we leave `Numberset2` alone and change `Numberset1` to `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` should the first line of output that starts with 15 be `15 1 1`?

Comment: Pattern: The first column should be in order of numbers in Numberset1, the second column for first number in Numberset1 should be in order of numbers in Numberset2, the 3rd column for first number in Numberset1 should be in order of numbers in NUmberset2 but when the 2nd column for first number in Numberset1 changes it should also change and print from 2ndnumber in Numberset2 list and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170513/discussion-between-python-newbie-and-pm-2ring).

Comment: @Python_newbie I'm glad we got it sorted out in the end. :)